Angular 17: mergeApplicationConfig in app.config.server.ts results in initialization of providers imported in app.config.ts
A standalone app generated with Angular 17 CLI imports the app.config.ts into the app.config.server.ts  and merges the 2 configurations by default.
This results in all providers imported in app.config.ts to also be imported into app.config.server.ts and hence to be instantiated on the server.
If a provider needed by the client uses sessionStorage inside the constructor, this results in an error, because sessionStorage is not defined on the server. E.g. like this:
export class MyStoreItem extends StoreItem <Stuff> {
  constructor() {
    const storedStuff: any = sessionStorage.getItem('stuff');
  }
}

I have tried removing the import of app.config.ts from app.config.server.ts, as well as the call to mergeApplicationConfig(appConfig, serverConfig). This fixes the issue and the app seems to work fine.
My question is, is it necessary to merge the 2 configurations in app.config.server.ts, and if so why?
And secondly, if it is necessary, how do I fix this issue without checking inside the provider's constructor whether it is called from server or browser, since it should actually never be called by the server.
Thank you!


Is it necessary to merge the 2 configurations in app.config.server.ts, and if so why?

Although few dependencies may vary (SessionStorage like you said) few are common for both (E.g: provideHttpClient(), provideRouter([])) It will be tedious to maintain duplicate code at two locations, hence we have mergeApplicationConfig(appConfig, serverConfig) to help you maintain the common dependencies better.

if it is necessary, how do I fix this issue without checking inside the provider's constructor whether it is called from server or browser, since it should actually never be called by the server.

The application will still work when you remove all of this, just that code will be duplicated in two places which you need to maintain, even if you remove the dependencies from app.config.server.ts there are still imports in the components which are shared by both the client and server code.
So it's a must to have code blocks which might error out on the server to use isPlatformBrowser to stop execution in the server.
Example of using isPlatformBrowser:
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';

export class MyStoreItem extends StoreItem <Stuff> {
    isBrowser: boolean;

    constructor( @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platFormId: Object) {
        this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platFormId);
        let storedStuff: any;
        // run code only on browser!
        if(this.isBrowser) {
            storedStuff = sessionStorage.getItem('stuff');
        }
    }
}


Hi Naren. Thank you very much for your answer. Just to clarify, are you saying that it is mandatory to check if code is run in the browser whenever I access something browser-specific like sessionStorage, even if I am in a class, which will conceptually never be used by the server?
And could you please give an example of the imports inside components you mentioned, which make this necessary?

@Tobi Suppose you have a logic related to session storage that runs on ngOnInit, there must be a if condition to stop the code from erroring, not all scenarios are needed, just the ones that cause console errors during application run!

So in my case, where the constructor of the provider (only needed by the client/browser) uses sessionStorage, I should add this check?

@Tobi We have a decorator specially for these scenarios, its @Optional if we add this to the constructor provider, even if its not present no errors will come, for other code, if condition is the solution if its errors out!

Now I am a little confused, since my constructor does not have any parameters. I have added some example code to my question. Could you please advise how to handle this case? Thank you for your patience!

Thank you! So in this case I need the check to avoid an error.
I am tempted to conclude, that the way providers are imported in standalone apps (Angular 17) is in this regard disadvantageous compared to the module based approach (Angular 15),
where I would be able to import providers on module level, which would ensure instanciation only in the browser and hence not requiring this check.
It seems the clean separation of client and server logic allowed with modules is somewhat broken in the standalone approach due to the mergeApplicationConfig logic.
Do you agree?

@Tobi Its a continuously improving process (Open Source) we have to trust the core developers and the direction the framework goes :) But overall I am happy with standalone, import sharing is still possible with shared modules if its needed!
